# remove subarray by key/value

Tags: php

I 'm looking for a way to remove subarrays by key/value search with a method like this : array_remove($array,$searchedKey,$searchedValue) :

example :

```
array(
     0 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 123,
           "address" => "brian@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 1
          ),
    1 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 124,
           "address" => "helen@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 1
          ),
    2 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 125,
           "address" => "albert@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 2
          )
```

)

If i'm searching this address : helen@gmail.com 
with array_remove ($myarray,"address","helen@gmail.com");

desired result :

```
array(
     0 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 123,
           "address" => "brian@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 1
          ),
    1 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 125,
           "address" => "albert@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 2
          )
```

)

or with a search on smtp key like this
array_remove($myarray,"smtp",1);

expected result :

```
array(
     0 => array
          ( 
           "userId"  => 125,
           "address" => "albert@gmail.com",    
           "smtp"    => 2
          )
```

)

i tried to use walk_array_recursive() to do so but i've failed.

Comment: If you want an R-based answer you should construct an example in R. These would NOT be represented with an R array. You would need a list to hold objects of varying types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this custom recursive function :

```
<?php
array_remove($array, "address", "helen@gmail.com");
var_dump($array);

array_remove($array, "smtp", 2);
var_dump($array);

function array_remove(array &$haystack, $needleKey, $needleValue, array &$parent = array(), $previousKey = null) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            array_remove($value, $needleKey, $needleValue, $haystack, $key);
        }elseif($key === $needleKey && $value === $needleValue) {
            unset($parent[$previousKey]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove($arr, $key, $val){
        $foundKey = '';
        foreach($arr as $k=>$a){
            if($a[$key] == $val){
                $foundKey = $k;
            }
        }
        return $foundKey;
    }

    $foundkey = remove($aa, 'address', 'helen@gmail.com');
```

Now unset the array

```
    if(isset($aa[$foundkey])){
        unset($aa[$foundkey]);
    }

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($aa);
```

Or if you want to return final array from the function, unset there and return the array instead of `$foundKey` like

```
function remove($arr, $key, $val){        
    foreach($arr as $k=>$a){
        if($a[$key] == $val){
            $foundKey = $k;
        }
    }
    if(isset($arr[$foundkey])){
        unset($arr[$foundkey]);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```